# Login Stored Procedure - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure for login. There are three parameters:
i) Email
ii) Password
iii) IsActive.
I want to check various aspects and return a bit value for each case.
I tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Login] 
    @Email VARCHAR(100),
    @Password VARCHAR(50),
    @ReturnValue INT
AS
BEGIN

    -- No User
    IF NOT EXISTS (Select * From AdminAccount Where Email=@Email and Password = @Password)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = 0
        END

    -- Active User
    ELSE IF EXISTS (Select * From AdminAccount Where Email=@Email and Password = @Password and IsActive='1')
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = 1
        END

    -- Not Active user
    ELSE IF EXISTS (Select * From AdminAccount Where Email=@Email and Password = @Password and IsActive='0')
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = 2
        END

    -- Email Not Exist
    ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (Select * From AdminAccount Where Email=@Email)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = 3
        END

    -- Password Not Match
    ELSE IF EXISTS (Select * From AdminAccount Where Email=@Email)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = 4
        END
END
```

Now the issue is it uses various SELECT Queries.
Is there any way to minimize or Optimize the code without losing meaning.

Comment: Why are you using a `bit` if you want to return 5 values?  Just declare the return value to be an `int`.

Comment: Are you really storing passwords as plain text?

Comment: Be careful here, this looks like it is quite possibly storing passwords in clear text. That is a major no win. Also, you might consider a different prefix than sp_ or even better, no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: That SP strongly suggests you're storing passwords as plain text. You should be salting and hasing it. Also, `@ReturnValue` is an **input** parameter in your SP, but you appear to be trying to use it as an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: One other thing....you should NOT return the reason why a login failed. Just that it failed. If you say things like "password invalid" you have confirmed the username is valid so a hacker can now simply use brute force.

Comment: You can just do a single query with `WHERE Email=@Email` and store the results in local variables. Then check your parameter values against the local variables instead of performing additional `SELECT` queries against your table.

Comment: IMHO, the answers to this question reduce the number of queries at the expense of readability. Are you _sure_ you have a performance problem, and that it can be solved by reducing the number of queries? Have you looked at the EXPLAIN?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question isn't about how to store passwords in a database, I will not be addressing that in this answer.

The first thing I must point out is that your procedure will never return the value 3. If the `Email` parameter does not match an account, your condition for returning 0 will always be met before the condition for returning 3 is evaluated. For that reason I've excluded it in this answer.

If your goal is to avoid multiple queries inside your stored procedure (a good idea), you can accomplish the same logic by using **a single query** and local variables. Here is a proof of concept using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

```
CREATE TABLE AdminAccount (
Email VARCHAR(100),
Password VARCHAR(50),
IsActive BIT
)

INSERT INTO AdminAccount (Email,Password,IsActive) VALUES    ('test@test.com','password',1)
INSERT INTO AdminAccount (Email,Password,IsActive) VALUES ('test2@test.com','password2',0)
INSERT INTO AdminAccount (Email,Password,IsActive) VALUES ('test3@test.com','password3',0)

SELECT * FROM AdminAccount

DECLARE @EmailParam VARCHAR(100) = 'test2@test.com'
DECLARE @PasswordParam VARCHAR(50) = 'password'
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT


DECLARE @LocalEmail VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @LocalPassword VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @LocalActive BIT

SELECT @LocalEmail = Email, @LocalPassword = Password, @LocalActive = IsActive FROM AdminAccount WHERE Email=@EmailParam

SET @ReturnValue = 
CASE 
    WHEN @LocalEmail IS NULL AND @LocalPassword IS NULL 
    THEN 0 -- No User
    WHEN @LocalPassword = @PasswordParam AND @LocalActive = 1 
    THEN 1 -- Active User
    WHEN @LocalPassword = @PasswordParam AND @LocalActive = 0
    THEN 2 -- Inactive User
    WHEN @LocalPassword <> @PasswordParam
    THEN 4 -- Invalid Password
END

SELECT @ReturnValue
```

Here is the updated stored procedure using the local variable logic above.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Login] 
    @Email VARCHAR(100),
    @Password VARCHAR(50),
    @ReturnValue INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare local variables to avoid multiple queries
    DECLARE @LocalEmail VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @LocalPassword VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @LocalActive BIT

    -- Gather data
    SELECT @LocalEmail = Email, @LocalPassword = Password, @LocalActive = IsActive FROM AdminAccount WHERE Email=@EmailParam

    SET @ReturnValue = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @LocalEmail IS NULL AND @LocalPassword IS NULL 
        THEN 0 -- No User
        WHEN @LocalPassword = @PasswordParam AND @LocalActive = 1 
        THEN 1 -- Active User
        WHEN @LocalPassword = @PasswordParam AND @LocalActive = 0
        THEN 2 -- Inactive User
        WHEN @LocalPassword <> @PasswordParam
        THEN 4 -- Invalid Password
    END

END
```

Comment: *"Since the question isn't about how to store passwords in a database, I will not be addressing that in this answer."* although true, that doesn't mean that the problems shouldn't be address. Both returning the reason for the login failure and using plain text storage for a password are both problems that need resolving.

Comment: Why use a bunch of `IF` statements here though; surely a single `CASE` expression and assignment would be far easier. `CASE WHEN @Email = Email AND @Password = Password AND Active = 1 THEN 0 WHEN ...`

Comment: Also, you haven't changed `@ReturnValue` to an `OUTPUT` parameter, it's still (only) an input parameter.

Comment: Updated to use more succinct case statements

Comment: @Larnu, the passwords could be hashed at the application level. I'm not making assumptions about the OP's environment. Although, I do agree that password security is important. However, I do not have enough information about the OP's environment to provide suggestions. This could be a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @AdminAccount table (Email  varchar(100), Pass  varchar(50), IsActive bit)

insert into @AdminAccount 
values ('mail1@m.com', 'abc', 1), ('mail2@m.com', '123', 0)

--Testing values
declare @Email VARCHAR(100) = 'mail2@m.com',
        @Password VARCHAR(50) = '123',
        @ReturnValue tinyint

--Temporary table: It avoid us to query the table many times
declare @userData table (Email  varchar(100), Pass  VARCHAR(50), IsActive bit)

    if exists ( select top 1 1 from @AdminAccount where Email = @Email ) 
        insert into @userData
        select Email, Pass, IsActive
        from @AdminAccount 
        where Email = @Email
    else
     begin
        if not exists ( select top 1 1 from @AdminAccount where Email = @Email and Pass = @Password ) 
            set @ReturnValue = 0
        else 
            set @ReturnValue = 3    --it will never return this value (3)
    end

    select  @ReturnValue = 
                        case 
                            when @Email = Email and @Password = Pass and IsActive = 1 then 1
                            when @Email = Email and @Password = Pass and IsActive = 0 then 2
                          else 4
                        end 
    from @userData 

    select @ReturnValue as RV
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AdminAccount WHERE Email=@Email)
 BEGIN
    SELECT  @ReturnValue = 
            CASE WHEN Password = @Password AND IsActive='1' THEN 1  -- Password match, Active User
                WHEN Password = @Password AND IsActive='0' THEN 2   -- Password match, Inactive User
                WHEN Password <> @Password AND IsActive='1' THEN 3  -- Active User, Password does not match
                WHEN Password <> @Password AND IsActive='0' THEN 4  -- Inactive User, Password does not match
                ELSE 0                                              -- Details (Email and Password) do not match 
            END
    FROM AdminAccount WHERE Email=@Email
END
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AdminAccount WHERE Email=@Email)
 BEGIN
    SET @ReturnValue = 0
END
```

Comment: This solution still uses multiple `SELECT` queries (3 total) when the OP asked for optimization.